# Working with regex and email validation, how do I limit the number of dot(.)?

Tags: regex

I have the following regex for email validation: `\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$\b`  Currently, it is saying this email format is valid: `john@company....com`. How do I fix my regex so that it is invalid to have more than one "." character?

Comment: Remove the `.` from `[A-Z0-9.-]+`? Alternatively, you can use `[A-Z0-9.-]*[A-Z0-9-]+` if you want to support dots in the hostname (or `[A-Z0-9.-]+(?<!\.)` if Lookbehinds are supported).

Comment: When you change that you'll need to allow more than one repetition of `[A-Z0-9-]+\.`. Otherwise it won't match `company.co.uk`.

Comment: Use a negative lookahead. Replace `\.` with `\.(?!\.)`. https://regex101.com/r/IzChAl/1

Comment: @Barmar the OP's question is about consecutive periods. This may give what the OP needs but does not answer the question.

Comment: @code That won't work in this case because `\.(?!\.)` will match the _last_ dot anyway.

Comment: @code There's little point making incremental fixes like this when he could just do it the right way.

Comment: @41686d6564 stands w. Palestine, thanks for the suggestion. I modified the regex to be: " \b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]*[A-Z0-9-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$\b ". However this domain is still consider to be valid: joe@company.....co.uk